# is it possible to print out the only first output from for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I would like to ask, is it possible to print out the output the only first output from for loop?

here is my current source code. in the `for i in tup[:1]` i am trying to set the output to print only first output but it does not work. even I delete the for loop, but the result gets the last output.

```
for row, cols in df.iterrows():
    cols_list = cols[cols>=0.98].index.tolist()
    if len(cols_list)>0:
        row_list = [row]*len(cols_list)
        tup = tuple(zip(row_list,cols_list))
        if len(tup) > 1:
            for i in tup[:1]:
                print(row, f' >0.98 {cols_list}')
    else:
        print(f'>0.98 {cols_list}')
```

here is the current output

```
 5  >0.98 [5, 30, 40, 42]
10  >0.98 [10, 30, 40, 42]
11  >0.98 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
12  >0.98 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44
```

but my expected output is to print it out only first output `5  >0.98 [5, 30, 40, 42]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `break` the loop after the 1st iteration:

```
for row, cols in df.iterrows():
    cols_list = cols[cols>=0.98].index.tolist()
    if len(cols_list)>0:
        row_list = [row]*len(cols_list)
        tup = tuple(zip(row_list,cols_list))
        if len(tup) > 1:
           print(row, f' >0.98 {cols_list}')
           break
    else:
        print(f'>0.98 {cols_list}')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to do it, but you can program it:

```
first_run = True
for i in range(10):
    if first_run:
        print("This is the first iteration of the loop!")
        first_run = False
    print(i)
```

But it looks like you simply want to print the first row of a pandas dataframe.  You might want to look at the [head() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html).

Answer (score 0):

how about this,

```
for i in range(10):
    print("This is the first iteration of the loop!")
    break
```